# One Way Relationship in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationship

Every restaurant must have Latitude and Longitude. However, every LatitudeLongitude object must not have "a restaurant"

So I have a one way relationship and generate a compiler warning.

What's the catch?

Should I use fetchRelationship instead? But what is fetchRelationship?

Why is it one way? Why does it have predicate? Why it is called fetch? I read the documentation and doesn't seem to get what it really is.

Answer (score 2):

You should use fetched properties (which are an collection of managed objects satisfying a specified fetch predicate) to represent one-way relationships. More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).

**Update**

You should probably use attributes in your case, otherwise you would add a fetched property to the `Restaurant` entity, set it's destination entity to `LatitudeLongitude` and store lattitude and longitude key-value pairs in its `userInfo` dictionary. Its fetch predicate would look like this:

```
($FETCH_SOURCE.longitude LIKE [c] $FETCHED_PROPERTY.userInfo.longitude) AND ($FETCH_SOURCE.latitude LIKE [c] $FETCHED_PROPERTY.userInfo.latitude)
```

Comment: Really? But what predicate would LatitudeLongitude object have?

Comment: Really, then what predicate should the LattitudeLongitude object has? Also each Restaurant should only have one LattitudeLongitude object. In fact, I probably should have made this an attribute rather than a relationship. However, I am just curious.

Comment: You're right, if you have no need to have `LatitudeLongitude` objects might as well use attributes for latitude and longitude. I've updated my answer with what you would do if you choose to use fetched properties.

Comment: What does [c] means in your predicate?

Comment: It makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Why use equal, why not use like

Comment: Sorry why use Like why not use equal?

Comment: LIKE is used for string comparison, look at the [Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

OK, super-old question, but here's how I'd be solving it now.

Not all relationships have to be filled. Keep your inverse (two-way) relationships but you don't necessarily have to link them.

```
+ (void)createRestaurantWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        Restaurant *localRestaurant;
        LatitudeLongitude *localLatLng1;
        LatitudeLongitude *localLatLng2;

        restaurant = [Restaurant MR_createInContext:localContext];

        localLatLng1 = [LatitudeLongitude MR_createInContext:localContext];
        localLatLng2 = [LatitudeLongitude MR_createInContext:localContext];

        restaurant.latLng = localLatLng1;
    }                 completion:completion];
}
```

By the time `completion` is called, both `localLatLng1` and `localLatLng2` exist, one is linked to a restaurant, one isn't.
Of course this method makes no sense in this form, it's just to prove the point that you can create objects without having to satisfy their relationships.

Z.